# composer wont load my files (PSR-4)

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I'm pretty new to composer and i have been trying to create a package, however i Have been having problems with getting my classes to load.

My file structure is the following

src/system/[myFiles.php]

Within the composer.json i have

```
    "autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
        "MicroSite\\": "src"
    }
}
```

I added the autoload.php in my index for testing but once i try to use the namespace it says it can't find the class

In my index.php i have the following:

```
require 'composer/autoload.php';
use Microsite\System\Database as Database;
$database = new Database;
$database->load_clients();
```

Within the Database.php i have the following namespace:

```
namespace MicroSite\system;
```

I have no idea what i'm missing.

Comment: You've `MicroSite ` in `"psr-4"` but used `use Microsite\System\Database`. Make the path/directories exact with same case.

Comment: have you tried to run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @TheAlpha DOH! that was the problem!! thank you for pointing it out!